# How can I correctly render the correct date format into a table using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, underscore.js

I'm trying to filter my JSON requests to match today's date. But when I render the data from the JSON it's in the incorrect format `(2018-03-04T00:00:00.000Z)`.

How can I do this using react in the render method?

```
   // Fetch data
    this.filterData();
    fetch('http://localhost:5005/games')
   .then((data) => data.json())
   .then((data) => this.setState( { live: data } ));

   // Filter data to match todays date
   var today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10);
   let db_datetime = new Date(res.DATE2019);
   let formatted_date2 = db_datetime.getFullYear()  + "-" + 
   (db_datetime.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + db_datetime.getDate() ;
   if(formatted_date1 === formatted_date2){return res}}
    })

   this.setState({
   filtered: ready
   });

    // Render out filtered data in table etc..
    <table>
    // How can I format this?
    <td>{item.DATE2018}</td>
    </table>
```

Comment: Show us how one object from the JSON data look like?

Comment: The date in the JSON is formatted as  {"DATE2018":"2017-10-16T23:00:00.000Z"}. The format I need is YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: Check out my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do complex data filtering stuff. Instead, just do this:

```
var today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10); // "2017-10-16"
// Check if this string is there.
const ready = this.state.live.filter(s => s.DATE2018.indexOf(today) === 0);
this.setState({
  filtered: ready
});
```

Map using `this.state.filtered` and you get the filtered states.

```js
var live = [{"DATE2018":"2017-10-16T23:00:00.000Z"}, {"DATE2018":"2019-05-08T23:00:00.000Z"}];
var today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10); // "2017-10-16"
// Check if this string is there.
const ready = live.filter(s => s.DATE2018.indexOf(today) === 0);
console.log(ready);
```